# How to install OE schema on Oracle XE(HR schema installed successfully)?

Tags: oracle, schema

I am studying OCA Oracle Database 11g SQL Fundamentals I Exam Guide: Exam 1Z0-051.
This book needs me to install HR and OE schemas from which I was able to install HR schema. I used the following link to download the scripts for the schemas:
[Sample Models and Scripts](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/sample-models-scripts-224531.html)

I installed the HR schema successfully and it has data in it.
But when I run the `oe_main.sql` I don't know what are the parameters to be supplied as they are not mentioned anywhere in the book, or Oracle's guide to install sample schemas from here :[Installing Sample Schemas](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/COMSC/installation.htm)
I am stuck on this step and I am guessing the further chapters of the book will require OE schema. I have installed `Oracle XE` on my own PC and using both 
`SQLCommandLine` and `Oracle Developer`.
On executing the script of `oe_main` I get following output which requires me to put the parameters:

```
specify password for OE as parameter 1:
Enter value for 1: root

specify default tablespeace for OE as parameter 2:
Enter value for 2: USERS

specify temporary tablespace for OE as parameter 3:
Enter value for 3: TEMP

specify password for HR as parameter 4:
Enter value for 4: root

specify password for SYS as parameter 5:
Enter value for 5: root

specify directory path for the data files as parameter 6:
Enter value for 6: C:/oraclexe/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/server/demo/schema/order_entry

writeable directory path for the log files as parameter 7:
Enter value for 7: C:/oraclexe/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/server/demo/schema/order_entry

specify version as parameter 8:
Enter value for 8: 1.0
```

which gives me the following output:

```
User dropped.

old   1: CREATE USER oe IDENTIFIED BY &pass
new   1: CREATE USER oe IDENTIFIED BY root

User created.

old   1: ALTER USER oe DEFAULT TABLESPACE &tbs QUOTA UNLIMITED ON &tbs
new   1: ALTER USER oe DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS QUOTA UNLIMITED ON USERS

User altered.

old   1: ALTER USER oe TEMPORARY TABLESPACE &ttbs
new   1: ALTER USER oe TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP

User altered.


Grant succeeded.


Grant succeeded.


Grant succeeded.


Grant succeeded.


Grant succeeded.

Connected.

Grant succeeded.

Connected.

Grant succeeded.


Grant succeeded.


Grant succeeded.


Grant succeeded.


Grant succeeded.


Grant succeeded.

Connected.

Session altered.


Session altered.

SP2-0310: unable to open file "C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server/demo/schema/order_entry/coe_1.0"
SP2-0310: unable to open file "C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server/demo/schema/order_entry/loe_1.0"
SP2-0310: unable to open file "C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server/demo/schema/order_entry/poe_1.0"

Session altered.

...creating subschema OC in OE

Type created.


Type created.


Type created.


Type created.


Type created.


Type created.


Type created.


Type created.


Type created.


Warning: Type created with compilation errors.


Type created.


Type created.


Type created.


Warning: Type created with compilation errors.


Type created.


Type body created.


Type created.


Type body created.


Type created.


Type body created.


Table created.

    FROM inventories i, warehouses w
                        *
ERROR at line 6:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


    FROM product_information p
         *
ERROR at line 10:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


     FROM customers c
          *
ERROR at line 20:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


     FROM customers c
          *
ERROR at line 20:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


     FROM customers c
          *
ERROR at line 20:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


    FROM orders o
         *
ERROR at line 9:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


 ON oc_orders FOR EACH ROW
    *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


 TABLE order_item_list OF oc_orders FOR EACH ROW
                          *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist



Commit complete.

    FROM oc_product_information o
         *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


    FROM oc_product_information o
         *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


    FROM oc_product_information o
         *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


    FROM oc_product_information o
         *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


    FROM oc_product_information o
         *
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


    FROM oc_product_information o
         *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


    FROM oc_product_information o
         *
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


    FROM oc_product_information o
         *
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


    FROM oc_product_information o
         *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


    FROM oc_product_information o
         *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


    FROM oc_product_information o
         *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


    FROM oc_product_information o
         *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


    FROM oc_product_information o
         *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


    FROM oc_product_information o
         *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


    FROM oc_product_information o
         *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


    FROM oc_product_information o
         *
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


    FROM oc_product_information o
         *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


    FROM oc_product_information o
         *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist



1 row created.


1 row created.


1 row created.


1 row created.


Type altered.


3 rows updated.


0 rows updated.


0 rows updated.


0 rows updated.


Commit complete.


Type body altered.


Type body altered.


Type body altered.


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

I don't know where I am going wrong but after many tries even if the schema is created when I fire select command, it shows no data in any tables.

Comment: Can you provide the parameters, that are asked you to enter during the execution of the script, which are confusing for you?

Comment: Edit your question to provide details,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are data models - there is no data.

'Sample Models and Scripts' - it's there to help you get started doing data modeling and design work with Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler.

If you want the schema and the data, go to [GitHub](https://github.com/oracle/db-sample-schemas).

Comment: Thank you. I  thought so! When I looked into the oe_main.sql script, I found only create commands. I seem to have downloaded the same scripts from some other site/blog. Will download from your link and try. But which one/ones do I need to execute to populate the tables and will those require any parameters? Thank you.

Comment: the gitbhub resources has instructions - let me know if you have specific questions

Comment: I try to execute the script mksample and get the following errors: 
`DROP USER oe CASCADE
          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01918: user 'OE' does not exist


DROP USER pm CASCADE
          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01918: user 'PM' does not exist


DROP USER ix CASCADE
          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01918: user 'IX' does not exist


DROP USER sh CASCADE
          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01918: user 'SH' does not exist


DROP USER bi CASCADE
          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01918: user 'BI' does not exist`

Comment: `Connected
SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/human_resources/hr_main.sql"
Connected
SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/order_entry/oe_main.sql"
Connected
SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/product_media/pm_main.sql"
Connected.
SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/info_exchange/ix_main.sql"
Connected.
SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/sales_history/sh_main.sql"
Connected.
SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/bus_intelligence/bi_main.sql"
Connected.
not spooling currently
SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/mkverify.sql" `

Comment: also I deleted my existing hr schema. Now lost all of it. :( This method seems too complicated to me.

Comment: Sorry and thanks! I forgot to change the '__SUB__CWD__' in the files. Pretty tedious work but I used simple trick. I opened half of all of the sql files using notepad++  and used **bold**replace in all open documents**bold** and replaced the above string with the working directory of schema as needed. I checked for the data in hr and oe, everything is as required. Didn't check for other schemas but I guess they are also populated.